# Help passing _POST Form Data PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I apologize in advance, I am a PHP noob!

I have form with some hidden fields. I need the values to POST to "submit_rma.php" so that they're not missing from the db--I need $qty, $estmate_id and $rma_type.

The rest of the fields are just displaying data for the user and are readonly. Currently I only get value from the qty text field.

Is there any easier way to pass these values? URL is out of the question due to security issues.

```
<form method="post" action="submit_rma.php";> 
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Quantity
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="qty" value="<?php echo $qty ?>" size="1"/><br/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
          Part #
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $model ?>" size="8" READONLY/><br/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Description
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $name_EN ?>" size="50" READONLY/><br/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Paid Date
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $sold_date ?>" size="6" READONLY/><br/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Amount Each
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $dealer_price ?>" size="8" READONLY/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
         <input type="hidden" name="estmate_id" value="<?php echo $estmate_id ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="rma_type" value="Short Shipped">
         <input type="submit" name="submit";">
</form>
```

Comment: If $qty, $estimate_id etc. are security relevant, sending them through POST is not going to help you much - they are still visible in the page's HTML source code, and being sent unencrypted. However, this is the normal way to send form data from one place to another. Whether it makes sense is not really possible to tell without knowing what the receiving script looks like. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Not so much security as it's too easy for something to break the db if my end users here mess with the URL. For example,  estmate_id is a has a one-to-many relationship in my db--I can't have it break my table relationships. Security isn't an issue since this is an intranet site.

Comment: To mess with a form as easy as with an url.

Comment: not when your values are readonly/hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a hidden `<INPUT>`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="<?= $qty ?>">
```

This won't show anything to the user. If you're unfamiliar, `<?= x ?>` is effectively equivalent to: `<?php echo x; ?>`.

However, this is a security problem, as an attacker could craft a fake request and put a different value into the field (sidestepping your page and doing the request directly). You should try and get the value some other way, such as through running the `INSERT` on page generation, then using an `UPDATE` on the POST, or something like that.

Comment: That's what I thought and tried...It's an internal site so it security is okay--no one here is smart enough to poison the POST. The value for qty POST correctly and I need user input there but rma_type and estmate_id however don't. When I echo them on the next page they're blank.

Comment: @Mikey1980 What do you echo? The same $qty thing? Ever heard of $_POST array?

Comment: LMAO, it appears I misspelled estimate--now both values POST--point to Lucas for the PHP tip!

Answer (score 0):

Am I pointing out the obvious to say that you forgot NAME attributes for all of the text boxes after "qty"?  The values won't persist beyond this page if the names aren't there :-)

Comment: Ok.  I haven't mocked up a test yet, but I'm wondering whether the POST is getting tripped up by an array of blank-named inputs.  The clue being that the qty comes through fine.   Oh well...